# Setting id for template in b-table of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can I set the `id` attribute for this `th` tag in the `b-table`? I have a `b-table` like this:

HTML:

```
  <b-table
    :items="group"
    :fields="columnsToDisplay"
    responsive>


    <template  slot="thead-top" slot-scope="data">
      <tr>
        <th id = "sample" style="background-color: #ffebcd; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle" rowspan="2" colspan="1">
          <span><strong>{{getValue1(key1)}}</strong></span></th>
        <th style="background-color: #ffebcd; font-size: small" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
          <span><strong>Desc:</strong> {{getValue2(key2)}}</span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th>-->
        <th style="text-align: center;background-color:#b9c0da" rowspan="1" colspan="5">
          <span><strong>Priorities</strong></span></th>
      </tr>
    </template>

  </b-table>
```

Javascript:

```
          getValue1: function (key) {
             let e = document.getElementById('sample')
             let url = 'https://example.com/' + this.arr[key].id
             e.setAttribute('href', url)
             return this.arr[key].id
         }
```

This simply errors out by returning `null` for value `e`. I basically want to set the `href` for a particular DOM element.

Comment: Looks like `e` is a `<th>` on which you are trying to set the `href` attribute, but there is no `href` attribute for that. Which DOM element are you trying to set the `href` on?

Comment: @RobMoll I want to set the href attribute on `{{getValue1(key1)}}` this value that is returned. Is there any other way I can do it?